# Seems CXF is not generating wsdl every time

Tags: tomcat, caching, wsdl, cxf, wadl

I am working on a CXF(spring) project(HUB). After deploying i am able to see soap and rest services list and I am opening this by two address. One is using localhost and second is using ip of my pc.So I am getting these output.

**Using localhost**

![Using localhost][1]

**Using ip**

![Using Ip][2]

But once i open any wsdl or wadl file from any output. It got reflect to other one and did not change until restart of server.
For example
I am opening wsdl file from first output(Using localhost) and then refresh output by Ip address then i got the output where endpoint shows localhost instead of ip.

Please help me. As i am working on F5 load balancer and in one domain creating more than one site. So each site is reflecting others wsdl file whatever opens first.

Comment: You can consider post the image here.

Comment: I tried .. but did not able to..You may click on above link...

Comment: @RohitRawat what version of CXF r u using

Comment: I am using cxf 2.7.4

Comment: I've seen caching problems like this too, and not just when generating WSDL/WADL. I would love to know what causes them. I'm guessing that something is storing what service host name is somewhere (maybe in a thread-specific cache?) but I really haven't managed to track it down.

Comment: hey Donal. please let me know if this is the solution of your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the answer.
With this following simple configuration in web.xml i was able to solve my problem.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>disable-address-updates</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

This is a side effect of cxf 2.7.x or earlier. Since 3.0.x this attribute is by default  true.

For more information visit this link.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5737